# UIManager, how to get values of different LookAndFeels?

Tags: java, swing, awt, look-and-feel, uimanager

I need to get the default background color of a `TableHeader` but of the Windows `LookAndFeel`. I have already tried:

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    System.out.println(UIManager.getColor("TableHeader.background"));
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it just returns the default color (so the Metal theme one). How do I get the background color of a component from a specific `LookAndFeel`?

**PS.**

In this case

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

is the same as

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
```

**EDIT:**

Ok I found out, why it returns a "wrong" value for `TabHeaader.background`. That's because the color I want is not the `TabHeader.background` or `TabHeader.foreground`. But do one know how one get the color of the "background"?

**EDIT 2:**

I found out, that `header.setBackground(COLOR);` works if you are on default theme. But when I set `LookAndFeel` on Windows look and feel `header.setBackground(COLOR)` changes the border color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows look and feel is defined in the [`LookAndFeel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/LookAndFeel.html) class [`com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/WindowsLookAndFeel.html). You can use it by invoking the `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` with fully qualified class name as an argument:

```
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        System.out.println(UIManager.getColor("TableHeader.background"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // HANDLE EXCEPTION
    }
```

This is the list of the available look and feels in the Swing framework: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#available

Hope this helps.

Comment: But thats exaclty what I tryed. I just get the values of the default LookAndFeel

Comment: Did you use `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel` as the argument to `setLookAndFeel`?

Comment: Yes. In my question I am using
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
Because I am using Windows it obviously is the same as
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

Comment: That is obviously not the same since your invocation to `getSystemLookAndFeelClassName` is most likely returning `javax.swing.plaf.metal`; because it is the look and feel you are getting (unless you have other default settings around). Just because you are on windows doesn't mean that swing is configured to work with the windows look and feel, so try the hardcoded string.

Comment: I have tryed the String already. It does not work. And i know it is the same cause I made 
System.out.println(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

Comment: Then I suggest to update the question to reflect this situation so it can be addressed appropriately. As it stands the question is incomplete/misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. I tried:

```
try
{
    System.out.println(UIManager.getColor("TableHeader.background"));
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    System.out.println(UIManager.getColor("TableHeader.background"));
}
catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

and got the following output:

```
javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=238,g=238,b=238]
javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=240,g=240,b=240]
```

So there is only a slight difference.

You can also verify the results by checking out [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) which displays all the properties for each LAF.

Comment: Mhm. I have tested what you have posted. I get the same Output as you, but I am wondering why it is 240, 240, 240 cause when I create a JTable with WindowsTheme it has white as background.